# Expected Number of Dishes in Indian Buffet Process?

Tags: nonparametric, stochastic-processes, nonparametric-bayes

I'm sure this question has an answer somewhere online, but I can't find it. Suppose I have an [Indian Buffet Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_buffet_process) with $T$ customers and concentration parameter $\alpha$. For those unfamiliar with the IBP, the IBP is a Bayesian nonparametric model defining a distribution over binary matrices $Z$ with $T$ rows (customers) and an infinite number of columns (dishes). Let $z_{t, k}$ denote the $t$th row and $k$th column of $Z$, and let $\Lambda_t$ denote the number of non-empty columns of $Z$ after the $t$th customer has sampled their dishes.

The IBP gives the following sequential sampling process:

The first customer samples $\lambda_1 \sim Poisson(\alpha/1)$ new "dishes". We set the first $\lambda_1$ entries in the first row of $Z$ to 1 i.e. $z_{1, k} = 1$ for $k \in [1, \lambda_t]$

Each subsequent customer does three things:

1. Samples dishes proportional to the number of previous customers who sampled that dish:

$$\forall k \leq \Lambda_t, \quad p(z_{t, k} \lvert z_{<t}, \alpha) = \frac{1}{t} \sum_{t' = 1}^T \delta (z_{t', k} = 1)$$

2. Samples $\lambda_t \sim Poisson(\alpha/t)$ new dishes. We set $z_{t, k} = 1$ for $k \in [\Lambda_{t-1}+1, \Lambda_{t-1} + \lambda_t]$
3. Add the number of new dishes to the previous number of total dishes i.e. $\Lambda_t \leftarrow \Lambda_{t-1} + \lambda_t$

My question: what is the expected number of non-empty columns (or equivalently, the expected number of sampled dishes) $\Lambda_t$?

Comment: Almost immediately after I posted this, I found a CMU reference (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10708-14/scribe_notes/scribe_note_lecture21.pdf) which says the number of non-empty columns is distributed $Poisson(\alpha H_T)$, where $H_T := \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{t}$. Can someone provide a derivation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized this problem has a straightforward answer almost immediately after posting :facepalm:

The easy answer is that each customer adds $\lambda_t$ new dishes and $\lambda_t \sim Poisson(\alpha / t)$. Consequently, by linearity of expectation, we have:

$$
\begin{align*}
\Lambda_t &= \sum_{t=1}^T \lambda_t\\
\mathbb{E}[\Lambda_t] &= \mathbb{E}[\sum_{t=1}^T \lambda_t]\\
&=\sum_{t=1}^T \mathbb{E}[\lambda_t]\\
&=\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{\alpha}{t}\\
&= \alpha \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{t}
\end{align*}
$$